# Passing in variable 'left' to jQuery animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm trying to pass in a variable called pixels to jquery animate. But it doesn't seem to be working. It won't allow my webpage to load when I do it like this (so I assume I'm not syntactically correct):

```
var options = {};
var pixels = 300;
options['left'] = pixels;
options['easing'] = "swing";

$( "#scroll" ).animate({
    options
});
```

This however, works fine but it's a static number which I don't want:

```
$( "#scroll" ).animate({
    easing: "swing",
    left: "-=300"
});
```

Comment: The first example is a syntax error. Have a look at the console and you should see `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` - Just remove `{` and `}` around `options`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the console? I think you have an error in your syntax:

```
var options = {};
var pixels = 300;
options['left'] = pixels;
options['easing'] = "swing";

$( "#scroll" ).animate(options);
```

You were passing `options` (an object itself) inside an object. Please [refer to the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more information.

Comment: Oops, dumb mistake on my part. Thanks that was it.

Comment: Then please mark this as the answer to your question :)